# Singleton Design Pattern and its child class's default constructor

Tags: java

In my coding, I use `Singleton` class with `Singleton Design Pattern`. Question is why its sub class does not allowed to use  default constructor?

I get compile time error :

```
Implicit super constructor Singleton() is not visible. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
```

Singleton.java

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleton;

    private Singleton() {
        System.out.println("I am user class");
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(singleton == null) {
            singleton = new Singleton();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

}
```

SubClass.java

```
public class SubClass extends Singleton {
    public SubClass(){
        System.out.println("I am sub class");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you subclass a singleton class, it's no longer a singleton.  You're doing it wrong.

Comment: The reason you can't create a subclass that compiles is because the singleton design pattern deliberately makes it impossible to subclass.  That's what having only private constructors does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create an instance of `SubClass` then it automatically invokes the `constructor` of its `SuperClass` to initialize its fields, and that further invokes all the superclass constructors in the `inheritance hierarchy`

Now since your `SuperClass` constructor is private, so it cannot invoke that. So, you are getting that exception..

But it doesn't make sense to `subclass` a `singleton` class, because in that case, `your class will no longer be singleton`.

You should `re-think` about your `design` and what you are trying to do. And `change` your design accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

SingleTon class are not supposed to be inherited so below ensures that

```
private Singleton() {
```

Below code

```
public SubClass(){
    System.out.println("I am sub class");
}
```

Is same as :

```
public SubClass(){
    super(); //Error here as super class constructor is private
    System.out.println("I am sub class");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Singleton` class no-arg constructor is `private`. When you instantiate sub-class it tries to instantiate super class also. But your super class has private constructor. It fails.

```
 private Singleton() {
        System.out.println("I am user class");
    }
```

It doesn't make sense to subclass `Singleton` class. You may need to re-think about your design.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, subclassing a singleton class is breaking the basics of `Singleton Pattern.`
Secondly, due to the chain of calling the constructors through the inheritance tree, you get that exception since the constructor of the parent class is `private`.

You will probably add a public constructor with some parameters to make the child inherit from its parent. Then you will have maybe many instances of `SubClass`. Any `Subclass` instance **IS-A** `Singleton` instance, too. And this is against the purposes of Singleton pattern. That's why you should avoid subclassing a singleton class.